# typescript nav and Nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-navigation

I'm learning typescript and I'm trying to build a navigation. I'm getting x Unexpected token `header`. Expected jsx identifier
,----
25 |

I don't know what to make of this. Can someone advise as to where the issue might be?

Navbar.tsx file:

```
  import Link from "next/link";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import NavItem from "./NavItem";

export interface INavbar {
  navActive: boolean;
  
}


//export function Navbar(props: INavbar) {
const Navbar: React.FC<INavbar> = (className, ...navProps) => {

  const [navActive, setNavActive] = useState(null);
  const [activeIdx, setActiveIdx] = useState(-1);
  
const MENU_LIST :{ text: string, href: string}[] = [
    { text: "Home", href: "/" },
    { text: "About Us", href: "/about" },
    { text: "Contact", href: "/contact" },
  ];
 
  return (

    
    <header>
      <nav className={`nav`}>
        <Link href={"/"}>
          <a>
            <h1 className="logo">KT</h1>
          </a>
        </Link>

        <div
          onClick={() => setNavActive(!navActive)}
          className={`nav__menu-bar`}
        >
       
        </div>
        <div className={`${navActive ? "active" : ""} nav__menu-list`}>
          {MENU_LIST.map((menu, idx) => (
            <div
              onClick={() => {
                setActiveIdx(idx);
                setNavActive(false);
              }
              key={menu.text}
            >
              <NavItem active={activeIdx === idx} {...menu} />
            </div>
          )
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>  
}

export default Navbar;
```

Navitem.tsx file:

```
import Link from 'next/link';

//Create a functional component with text, href and active as props and use Link from next/link to link pages
export interface INavItem {
  text: string;
  href: string;
  active: boolean;
}

const NavItem: React.FC<INavItem> = ({ text, href, active }) => {
  return (
    <Link href={href}>
      <a className={`nav__item ${active ? 'active' : ''}`}>{text}</a>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default NavItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some parenthesis/brackets. Your Navbar should look like this:

```
              }} <--- Added a bracket here
              key={menu.text}
            >
              <NavItem active={activeIdx === idx} {...menu} />
            </div>
          ))} <--- Added a parenthesis and a bracket
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>  
)} <--- Added a parenthesis
```

One more issue is that the props passed to a component are passed as a single object, but in `Navbar` they are being used as if multiple objects were passed in.

Try changing:

```
const Navbar: React.FC<INavbar> = (className, ...navProps) => {
```

to:

```
const Navbar: React.FC<INavbar> = ({className, ...navProps}) => {
```

Now we are properly using the interface `INavbar`, but `className` is not expected in `INavbar`, so we need to either add `className` to `INavbar` or remove it from the props destructuring assignment. In this case, `className` is not being used anywhere, so we can remove it:

```
const Navbar: React.FC<INavbar> = ({...navProps}) => {
```

We *are using* `navActive`, but we are not using `navProps` anywhere, so we can further adjust what props are being destructured:

```
const Navbar: React.FC<INavbar> = ({ navActive }) => {
```

It looks like you are trying to use navActive as a props, and you are also defining it with `useState`... You can only do one or the other since `navActive` can't be *both* a state variable *and* a prop.

I'm guessing you want to pass it in as a prop, so the next instructions will be based on that assumption. In that case, we can go ahead and remove this line:

```
const [navActive, setNavActive] = useState(null);
```

Now we are getting the error `Cannot find name 'setNavActive'`. We'll need to define `setNavActive`, and since `navActive` is being passed in as a props, we'll have `setNavActive` also be passed in as a prop:

```
export interface INavbar {
  navActive: boolean;
  setNavActive: (value: boolean) => void;
}

const Navbar: React.FC<INavbar> = ({ navActive, setNavActive }) => {
```

Notice we set the type of `setNavActive` to be `(value: boolean) => void` in our `INavBar`. This means `setNavActive` is a function which expects one parameter of type `boolean` (called value).

Since we added `setNavActive` as an expected prop, Typescript now helps us out by telling us where `<Navbar />` is used that `Property 'setNavActive' is missing`.

Wherever you are using `Navbar`, we now need to make sure we are passing in `navActive` and `setNavActive` as props like this:

```
<Navbar navActive={navActive} setNavActive={setNavActive} />
```

In that same component we also want to define `navActive` and `setNavActive` using `useState`. We will initialize `navActive` to `false`, since we defined `navActive` as a boolean:

```
const [navActive, setNavActive] = useState(false);
```

That is a lot of instructions, but I hope it was helpful. It may be useful to look at all of my suggestions applied at once, so I've created a full example on CodeSandbox where you can see everything working:
[image: Edit Navbar Debug]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't close the paranthesis in the return statement

```
return (
  <header>
   ...
  </header>
)
```

Comment: I must've forgot to add it in my question though after running it again on my terminal I still get the sane error after adding to the )...

Comment: This error could also occur if the closing element does not match, e.g. `return (<header></mismatched.header>)`